# Voto majoritário em matriz no R

Tags: r, matriz

quero comparar elementos de uma matriz, por exemplo, na linha 1 (fixada) quero saber qual objeto acontece com maior frequência e retorno o mesmo, preciso de forma automatizada, pois o número de colunas é variável.

Segue um exemplo do código:

```
M = 3
a = matrix(sample(1:2, 300, replace = T), ncol = M)
combinado = rep(0, nrow(a))

i = 1
while(i <= nrow(a)){
  if(sum(a[i,]) == 3||sum(a[i,]) == 4) combinado[i] = 1
  else combinado[i] = 2
  i = i + 1
}
```

Onde eu gostaria de variar o M, respeitando a dimensão da matriz claro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso facilmente usando uma combinação de `apply` com `table`:

```
count <- apply(a, 1, function(r) as.numeric(names(which.max(table(r)))))
```

Temos que usar `as.numeric` porque `names` retorna um resultado de strings.

Demonstrando o resultado:

```
> identical(combinado, count)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Como você quer saber o valor de maior frequência em cada linha, eu sugeriria fazer um `lapply` da função `table` por linha e depois verificar o valor de maior frequência:

```
sapply(lapply(split(a, row(a)), table), function(x) names(which.max(x)))
  [1] "2" "1" "2" "2" "2" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "2" "2" "1" "1" "1" "1" "2" "1" "2"
 [22] "1" "1" "2" "1" "1" "2" "1" "1" "1" "2" "1" "2" "2" "2" "2" "1" "1" "1" "2" "2" "1"
 [43] "2" "2" "1" "2" "2" "1" "2" "1" "1" "1" "1" "2" "1" "2" "1" "2" "1" "2" "1" "2" "2"
 [64] "1" "2" "1" "2" "1" "2" "1" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "1" "1" "2" "2" "1" "2" "2" "1" "2"
 [85] "1" "2" "1" "2" "2" "1" "1" "1" "1" "2" "1" "2" "1" "1" "1" "2"
```

Demonstrando que os resultados são iguais aos seus:

```
all.equal(combinado, as.numeric(sapply(lapply(split(a, row(a)), table), function(x) names(which.max(x)))))
[1] TRUE
```

Note que com os `apply` agora o cálculo não depende do número de colunas da matriz. Fazendo com `M = 5`:

```
M = 5
a = matrix(sample(1:2, 300, replace = T), ncol = M)
sapply(lapply(split(a, row(a)), table), function(x) names(which.max(x)))
 [1] "2" "2" "1" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "1" "2" "1" "2" "2" "2" "2" "1" "2" "2" "1" "2"
[22] "1" "1" "2" "1" "2" "1" "1" "1" "2" "1" "2" "2" "2" "1" "1" "1" "2" "2" "2" "1" "2"
[43] "2" "2" "2" "2" "1" "1" "2" "1" "2" "2" "1" "2" "2" "1" "2" "2" "2" "2"
```

Comment: Carlos, na sua solução se aumentarmos o tamanho de M para 11, por exemplo, ele cria uma lista vazia.

Comment: @WagnerJorge perfeito Wagner, realmente isso acontece porque `apply` tenta simplificar o resultado para uma matriz. Não tinha pensado nessa situação. Para evitar que isso ocorra é basta usar o `lapply` nas linhas ao invés do `apply`, alterei a resposta.